# Deployment error on heroku

Tags: deployment, heroku

I deployed my small application successfully on Heroku , and when I try to check its functioning , it gives the following error.

```
2011-05-13T07:04:01+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::EACCES (Permission denied - /app/tmp/stream20110513-1-qan7po-020110513-1-19mvzny-0 or /app/public/system/photos/5/medium/Splash-Bird.png):
2011-05-13T07:04:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/products_controller.rb:47:in `create'
2011-05-13T07:04:01+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/products_controller.rb:46:in `create'
2011-05-13T07:04:01+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-05-13T07:04:01+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Has this something to do with the permissions? Because this `Permission denied` error is occurring for different actions time again. Please guide.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are trying to store data on your Heroku instance, [which is not allowed](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem). Use another place to store your images, why not try [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com)?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using Paperclip, which defaults to storing the images and thumbnails on the local filesystem. As Pal mentioned, you cannot write files on Heroku. Luckily, Paperclip has built in support for storing to S3. "You can find more information about S3 storage at the description for Paperclip::Storage::S3."